# Eloquent / Laravel - Putting a WHERE Clause on a Reference Table With Chained Relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following relationship functions in my `Job` model:

```
public function resourceTypes(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('ResourceType', 'job_requests');

}

public function resources(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('Resource', 'jobs_resources')->withPivot('flow_type', 'resource_type_id');

}
```

I am able to get an object with data from both of the above relationships using:

```
$job = Job::findorfail($projectId);
$result = $job->with('resources.resourceTypes')->get();
```

I would like to put a where clause on the `jobs_resources` pivot table - specifically on the column `flow_type`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following statement:

```
Job::with(['resources' => function ($query){
   $query->wherePivot('flow_type', '=', '1' );
}, 'resources.resourceTypes'])->where('id', $projectId)->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$job = Job::with('resources' => function($q) {
   $q->with('resourceTypes')->where('flow_type',2);
})->findorfail($projectId);
```

In above you will get only those resources with `flow_type = 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = DB::table('job')
        ->join('job_resources', 'job.id', '=', 'job_resources.job_id')
        ->join('job_requests', 'job_resources.request_id', '=', 'job_requests.id')
        ->where('job_resources.flow_type', '=', CONDITION)
        ->get();
```

Your table data is not clear from your input, but this method (query builder) should work